# SQL Replication, CE device

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, merge-replication

I have a Windows CE device that I'd like to replicate data to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I understand the basics of replication and I need to use MSDN's "Two-Server Topology". Where there is an IIS box and a separate SQL Server box.

I have replication and a publication set up on the SQL database. Also, on the IIS box I created a virtual directory and via UNC have the physical folder on the database box. So the virtual dir path on the IIS box looks something like "\databasebox\c$\Replications".  I set up a user on both boxes and am able to test the connection successfully.

I'm able to browse to the virtual directory from the device via a path such as:  "https://www.mydomain.com/Replications" and with directory browsing turned on I can see the sqlcesa35.dll.

The issue is adding the subscription.  Using the Web Synchronization Wizard, I cannot complete the process.  I get to the point where I'm configuring the existing virtual directory.  Choose it and get an error "ConnWiz - The local path is not in the correct format".  If I use the wizard to create a new virtual dir and get tot he point of adding the remote directory UNC it does not allow it.

I've tried mapped drives, not allowed.  This has to be possible, its part of Microsoft's "Two-Server Topology".

How do I create a replication subscription on IIS box-1 where the virtual directory points to a folder on box-2?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is related to IIS 7&8 support of Web Synchronization wizard. According to this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152511.aspx) "The Configure Web Synchronization Wizard is not supported on IIS 7.0.". What you need is to do manual configuration of IIS for Web Synchronization. You can find the steps to do that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714039.aspx).